# Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. Ekko lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, lightbox

I'm creating a modal with some thumbnails that I want to be opened in a lightbox when I click on them,
but when I click on a thumb I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined                          ekko-lightbox.js:97
```

ekko-lightbox.js:97:

```
this._isBootstrap3 = $.fn.modal.Constructor.VERSION[0] == 3;
```

the code of my thumb:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
<a href="https://cryptoid.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/novo-modelo-rg-verso-700x468.jpg" target="_blank" style="position: absolute;" title="baixar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<i class="fas fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="https://cryptoid.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/novo-modelo-rg-verso-700x468.jpg" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="lightbox">
<img src="https://cryptoid.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/novo-modelo-rg-verso-700x468.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="documento anexado 1">
</a>
</div>
```

Ekko lightbox calling code:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault(); 
     $(this).ekkoLightbox(); 
});
```

my modal:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug in your plugin itself. In its source code, `$.fn.modal.Constructor.VERSION` is not defined, there's not much you can do about it but open an issue on Github, I guess

Comment: Make sure you have loaded all the dependencies (jquery and bootstrap) **before** `ekko-lightbox.js`. Please show how you load them.